# Issue in mvc posting a new table and recording that tables ID in another table in the same post command

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, save, edmx

Ok so I've tried a number of different ways which work some times and don't others so I'd rly like to find out the sure fire way to ensure this process works correctly.

I have 4 tables with 1 table storing the other 3 tables Id upon each page submit.

Table One is created at the same time as table Two with table two being the form table and one just being a way to connect all 4 together

```
One O = new One();
_db.Twos.AddObject(T);
O.TId = T.Id;
_db.Ones.AddObject(O);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

this works but the other 2 tables have issues with 3 working and 4 breaking even with the same code as 3.

1 solution that I'd hate to use would be to pass each table via session or a model object right till the end and then submit them all together but that would open it up to more problems I think.

Edit-

I'm not exactly sure what else I can add but the basic problem is I have 1 core table with 3 sub tables and new records gets created in each table at different times.

3 saves

1st = new core record + 1 new sub table record      - works

2nd = update core record + 1 new sub table record   - works

3rd = update core record + 1 new sub table record   - breaks

2nd/3rd save example code with Th being the table object passed in which represents the 3rd table and O being the core table as shown in the code near the top

```
O.Three = Th;
_db.SaveChanges();
```

This correctly pulls the ID and saves it to the core table on the 2nd save but not on the 3rd save even tho it's the same code and the tables have the same connections.

Each pull - OId being the Core tables Id so each table knows where to save too.

```
public ActionResult Three(int OId, FormCollection fc)
```

Each Push

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Three(Three Th, FormCollection fc)
```

As nothing else but the references changes I think thats about it else which is relevant since everything it basically date/time assignments to table values which then get checked if ModelState.IsValid before it trys to save changes.

I've also tried to use UpdateModel but that hasn't worked either so anybody know of any other solutions for this ?

Comment: This is really vague, can you clean it up a little so we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id from the database for T.id in the line O.TId = T.Id; will not be relevant at that point in your code.  You must call saveChanges(); for the id to be fed into the object.

Try:

```
One O = new One();
_db.Twos.AddObject(T);
_db.SaveChanges();
O.TId = T.Id;
_db.Ones.AddObject(O);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Dunno why this was causing an issue originally but I noticed this is how I do it in vs12 and never had an issue so marking this as correct.